# Boost python: passing large data structure to python

Tags: python, c++, boost

I'm currently **embedding** Python in my C++ program using boost/python in order to use matplotlib. Now I'm stuck at a point where I have to construct a large data structure, let's say a dense 10000x10000 matrix of doubles. I want to plot columns of that matrix and I figured that i have multiple options to do so:

1. Iterating and copying every value into a numpy array --> I don't want to do that for an obvious reason which is doubled memory consumption
2. Iterating and exporting every value into a file than importing it in python --> I could do that completely without boost/python and I don't think this is a nice way
3. Allocate and store the matrix in Python and just update the values from C++ --> But as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281855/performance-of-boost-python) it's not a good idea to switch back and forth between the Python interpreter and my C++ program
4. Somehow expose the matrix to python without having to copy it --> All I can find on that matter is  about **extending** Python with C++ classes and not **embedding**

Which of these is the best option concerning performance and of course memory consumption or is there an even better way of doing that kind of task.

Comment: 5) write some additional code to extract only the columns that you want to plot and return the (much smaller) relevant data to Python for plotting.

Comment: From an object lifetime and ownership perspective, Boost.Python makes no distinction between extending and embedding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent copying in Boost.Python, one can either:

- Use policies to [return internal references](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/python/doc/v2/return_internal_reference.html)
- Allocate on the free store and use policies to have Python [manage the object](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/python/doc/v2/manage_new_object.html)
- Allocate the Python object then [extract](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/python/doc/v2/extract.html#extract-spec) a reference to the array within C++
- Use a smart pointer to share ownership between C++ and Python

---

If the matrix has a C-style contiguous memory layout, then consider using the Numpy C-API.  The [`PyArray_SimpleNewFromData()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#c.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData) function can be used to create an ndarray object thats wraps memory that has been allocated elsewhere.  This would allow one to expose the data to Python without requiring copying or transferring each element between the languages.  The [how to extend documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/c-info.how-to-extend.html#c.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData) is a great resource for dealing with the Numpy C-API:

> Sometimes, you want to wrap memory allocated elsewhere into an ndarray object for downstream use. This routine makes it straightforward to do that. [...] A new reference to an ndarray is returned, but the ndarray will not own its data. When this ndarray is deallocated, the pointer will not be freed.
>
> [...]
>    If you want the memory to be freed as soon as the ndarray is deallocated then simply set the `OWNDATA` flag on the returned ndarray.

Also, while the plotting function may create copies of the array, it can do so within the C-API, allowing it to take advantage of the memory layout.

---

If performance is a concern, it may be worth considering the plotting itself:

- taking a sample of the data and plotting it may be sufficient depending on the data distribution
- using a raster based backend, such as [Agg](http://matplotlib.org/glossary/index.html#term-agg), will often out perform vector based backends on large datasets
- benchmarking other tools that are designed for large data, such as [Vispy](http://vispy.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Altough Tanner's answer brought me a big step forward, I ended up using [Boost.NumPy](https://github.com/ndarray/Boost.NumPy), an inofficial extension to Boost.Python that can easily be added. It wraps around the NumPy C API and makes it more save and easier to use.